# CSS Animation Delay for individual divs

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to get three items to come in one after the other. So far they are all using the same animation and the delay is working but I would like to seperate them out so the each come in 1.5s apart. I want to avoid repeating all of the animation code in CSS. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!-- FOOTER TAGLINE -->
        <div id="ftr-tagline">
            <div id="ftr1-animation" class="slideLeft">
                <div class="one-third">
                    <div class="one-call">
                        One Call...
                    </div><!-- .one-call -->
                </div><!-- .one-third -->
            </div><!-- #ftr1-animation -->
            <div id="ftr2-animation" class="slideLeft">
                <div class="one-third">
                    <div class="one-contact">
                        One Contact...
                    </div><!-- .one-contact -->
                </div><!-- .one-third -->
            </div><!-- #ftr2-animation -->
            <div id="ftr3-animation" class="slideLeft">
                <div class="one-third last">
                    <div class="one-culture">
                        One Culture...
                    </div> <!-- .one-contact -->
                </div><!-- .one-third -->
            </div> <!-- #ftr3-animation -->
        </div> <!-- #ftr-tagline -->
        <!-- END FOOTER TAGLINE -->
```

CSS:

```
/* ANIMATIONS */

#title-animation, #ftr1-animation, #ftr2-animation, #ftr3-animation{
    /*background-color: #fe5652;*/
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
==============================================
slideLeft
==============================================
*/


.slideLeft{
    animation-name: slideLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;  

    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 1.5s;

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {transform: translateX(150%);}   
    100% {transform: translateX(0%);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(150%);}       
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying the delay to all three divs (`.slideLeft`), apply the delay separately to each div:

```
#ftr2-animation {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

#ftr3-animation {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8jTg5/

Comment: That works great! Now, any idea to have them not visible until the delay time is up? I changed the CSS to: 
#title-animation, #ftr1-animation, #ftr2-animation, #ftr3-animation{
 visibility: hidden;
}

#ftr1-animation{
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
#ftr2-animation{
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
#ftr3-animation{
 -webkit-animation-delay: 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-delay: 4s; 
}

Comment: If you look at my fiddle demo you'll see that they are hidden until the animation starts. visibility:visible is set inside the @keyframes.